# Do i need to remove observer when my object destroys?

Tags: cocoa

Do I need to remove an observer from an object that will be released?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIFICATION object:obj]
```

or is it done automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to remove it manually, as if not, and the notification center tries to send it a message, it will crash.

Comment: Yes, it is. Dealloc is perfectly for these kind of cleanup tasks.